# where does the energy go when reducing the pressure of a simple piston system?

Tags: thermodynamics

In thermodynamics we're learning about energy in a system, the lecturer proposed a simple piston system that when you push on you do work to the gas inside the piston and it increases the temperature, however I got thinking about what happens if you pull on the piston? since you're reducing the pressure of the system wouldn't that reduce the overall temperature, but you're also putting work into pulling the piston against the outside pressure? Does it have something to do with putting work into the external atmosphere instead of the air inside the piston, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When pulling the piston, the gas inside actually does work.

The force exerted by the piston (due to the pressure) is the same direction of the displacement of the piston, so the work done is positive.  On the other hand, the external atmosphere is exerting a force that is opposite to the displacement of the piston, so the work done is negative.

In reality, what's actually happening is that the atmosphere gains more energy than the energy you put into pulling the piston, therefore the net result is a gain in energy.  This come from lowering the temperature of the gas inside the piston.